# NIC Copper Link is Down

Tags: networking, server

Im seeing the below error

[7483226.934281] bnx2 0000:01:00.0 en01: NIC Copper Link is Down in Linux server.

Also the Sudo Terminal or console for command prompt is not visible in Ubuntu.

I need to check the IP address assigned to server.

Request help to understand the error and how to fix the same.

Comment: Please provide OS & release details; you've said Ubuntu but provided no clues as to which product you're asking about. Is this a Ubuntu Core server?  a standard Ubuntu Server? etc... and what release are you asking about...   Are you sure the connection/link isn't actually *down* ?

Comment: The "en01" is remarkably similar to Debian's `eno1` name for network devices. Does your server have an Intel network device that uses the `e1000e` driver? Are you working with LXD containers? If so, the solution may be rather simple ... so long as you're actually running Ubuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include the exact version of the server as well as the output of `lshw -c network`?

Comment: The Ubuntu version is 20.04

Comment: It is Ubuntu core server